# SMB Server with JLAN on Android : can't see share folder from PC or MAC

Tags: android, server, smb, android-sharing

I'm trying to run a server on a Android device using the JLAN library.
After some works, it seems running, stopping.
From an other Android device, I can connect and see my share folder by adding manually a server with smb://192.168.0.10:1445.

Here my problems:

1) I rooted the Android Device but I can't use the port above 1024. (So I use 1445 instead 445)

2) From any other device, I can't see automaticaly my server.
It seems my netbios or my broadcast configuration is incorrect.

3) I tried connect it from a MAC like a "anonym" with smb://192.168.0.10:1445.
The authentication windows appears but when I confirm MAC said that I have no the right or that there is not any share folder.

Code of my files:

My Xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
   <jlanserver>
      <servers>
         <SMB/>
         <noFTP/>
         <noNFS/>
      </servers>
      <SMB>
         <host name="serveur" domain="Workgroup">
            <broadcast>255.255.0.0</broadcast>
            <smbdialects>Core,LanMan,NT</smbdialects>

            <netBIOSSMB sessionPort="1139" namePort="1137" datagramPort="1138" platforms="linux,solaris,macosx,windows"/>
            <tcpipSMB platforms = "linux,macosx,windows,solaris" port = "1445"/>

            <comment>SMB Android Server</comment>
         </host>

         <authenticator type="local">
            <class>org.alfresco.jlan.server.auth.LocalAuthenticator</class>
            <mode>USER</mode>
            <Debug/>
            <allowGuest/>
         </authenticator>

         <!-- Debug -->
            <sessionDebug flags="Netbios,State,Negotiate,Tree,Transact,Echo"/>
            <netbiosDebug/>
            <announceDebug/>
      </SMB>

      <shares>
         <diskshare name="ESPACE" comment="Dossier de Partage">
            <driver>
              <class>org.alfresco.jlan.smb.server.disk.JavaFileDiskDriver</class>
              <LocalPath>/tmp</LocalPath>
            </driver>

            <size totalSize="2T" freeSize="100G"/>-->
            <accessControl default="Write"/>
         </diskshare>
      </shares>

      <security>
         <authenticator type="local">
            <class>org.alfresco.jlan.server.auth.LocalAuthenticator</class>
            <mode>USER</mode>
            <Debug/>
            <allowGuest/>
         </authenticator>
      </security>

      <shareMapper>
         <class>org.alfresco.jlan.smb.server.DefaultShareMapper</class>
         <debug/>
      </shareMapper>
```

My Main Class:
(Launchserver and StopServer are called clicking buttons in my activity)

```
package archisoft.com.smbserverandroid;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.alfresco.jlan.app.XMLServerConfiguration;
import org.alfresco.jlan.smb.server.CIFSConfigSection;
import org.alfresco.jlan.smb.server.SMBServer;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Configuration extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final String TAG = "ServiceServerSMB";
    private Button stopButton = null;
    private Button startButton = null;
    private XMLServerConfiguration srvConfig;

    SMBServer MonServer;

    // A la création
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "####### onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);
    }

    // Au redémarrage
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "####### onStart");
        super.onStart();
        // On bind les boutons
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
    }

    // Au retour sur l'activité
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "####### onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    // A l'arrêt
    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "####### onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "####### onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    // Destruction
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "####### Destruction");
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    // Appelé lorsque l'on clique sur "Start Server"
    public void LaunchServer(View view)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "####### Launch server");

                try {
                    InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jlanconfiguration);
                    srvConfig = new XMLServerConfiguration();
                    srvConfig.loadConfiguration(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                    ((CIFSConfigSection) srvConfig.getConfigSection(CIFSConfigSection.SectionName)).setDatagramPort(1138);
                    ((CIFSConfigSection) srvConfig.getConfigSection(CIFSConfigSection.SectionName)).setNameServerPort(1137);
                    ((CIFSConfigSection) srvConfig.getConfigSection(CIFSConfigSection.SectionName)).setSessionPort(1139);

                    CIFSConfigSection cifsConfig = (CIFSConfigSection) srvConfig.getConfigSection(CIFSConfigSection.SectionName);

                    MonServer = new SMBServer(srvConfig);
                    MonServer.startServer();

                    Log.d(TAG, "Lancement serveur");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Erreur lancement serveur", e);
                }
    }

    public void StopServer(View view)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "####### StopServer");

        MonServer.shutdownServer(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all people who will try to help me.
Any advice would be welcome.

If you have any question, feel free to ask.

Best regards!

Anthony

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the shared folder in PC from android mobile by using jcifs which is cool please try this [link](http://blog.icodejava.com/875/java-tutorial-using-jcifs-to-copy-files-to-shared-network-drive-using-username-and-password/) pass your username and password and u can get all the shared folders by just one step smbFile.listfiles(). try it it worked for me.

Comment: I'll give a try. Thanks you for the link.

Comment: Hi, the question was about "How to create a server", not "How to create a client".